# Is it possible universal link implementation without AASA file for under development project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, flutter

I am developing a flutter project and got stuck in **universal linking/deep linking**.
Is it possible in universal linking implementation without AASA file for under development project, only want to open application for now, later when I got app-id will upload AASA.

Comment: you need that file

Comment: Thanks for your answer.